# double-quoted include, expected angle-bracketed instead

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, fastlane

I've got a React Native App that is built by fastlane via Gitlab that is giving the following error:

.......node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGEnums.h:10:10: double-quoted include "YGMacros.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead [-Werror,-Wquoted-include-in-framework-header]
#include "YGMacros.h"

Found this article:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651941

.gitlab-ci.yml has the following script to build the IOS app.

```
  script:
  - rm -rf node_modules
  - nvm use
  - npm install
  - cd ios
  - rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
  - rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
  - sudo gem install bundler:1.17.2
  - sudo bundle update
  - sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
  - bundle exec fastlane beta
```

It appears the cocoapods install gets the correct version:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.10.0.rc.1
```

I'm still getting the double-quotes error

Comment: Might be different CocoaPods versions in the bundler and outside of it. Try `pod --version` and `bundle exec pod --version`

Comment: @PaulBeusterien You were right. Bundler is using 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by putting this in the Gemfile in ios folder:
gem 'cocoapods', '1.10.0.rc.1'

Thanks @PaulBeusterien for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find pods, open buildsettings
2. Search for quoted include,
3. Set this attribute to No